# How to correct setup IIS express for x64 platform app

Tags: windows-7-x64, iis-express

I have IIS 7.5 that configure for work with x64 applications.

I want use IIS Express for test my application before deploy to local IIS.
 But IIS Express don't want to run my X64 application.

What should I setup for run IIS Express with  X64 application ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

currently IIS Express runs only as 32-bit application!

Comment: Any updates on this? Is IISExpress still 32bit only?

Comment: IIS Express 7.5 is still 32 bit only, but IIS Express 8.0 has both 32 and 64 bit version support.

Comment: thanks! I've done some reading and it turns out that while IIS Express 8.0 has an x64 binary, WebMatrix and Visual Studio cannot talk to the 64 bit version :(